# How can i remove a word from a string using the index in python?

Tags: python

I have used `.find()` on my string to find the index of the word that the user wants to remove from the string, but now how do i use this index to them remove said word?

The function is as follows:

```
sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
print("The sentence is: "+ sentence)

user_removal = input("Which word would you like to remove? ")
user_removal_word = sentence.find(user_removal)
```

I've used if statements and then formatting to then remove the word from the sentence and then recreate it but I'm sure that there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Pls add some examples like how you used `find()` and string you used along with your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing.

**Usage**

somestring[lowerborder:upperborder].

**Example**

```
sentence = "The.quick.brown.fox.jumps.over.the.lazy.dog."
print("The sentence is: "+ sentence)

user_removal = input("Which word would you like to remove? ")

lowerborder = sentence.find(user_removal) -1
upperborder = lowerborder + len(user_removal) +1

firstPart = sentence[:lowerborder]
secondPart = sentence[upperborder:]

result = firstPart + secondPart

print(result)
```

> Input: 'fox'
>
> Output: 'The.quick.brown.jumps.over.the.lazy.dog.'

**Explanation**

The approach is to determine both borders, being the index where the word you are trying to remove starts (lowerborder) and where it ends (upperborder).

You then generate a new string (firstpart) that contains everything of your initial string, up to the lowerborder.

After that you generate a second string, that picks up right after the word you are trying to remove and contains everything after said word.

You then put both together and have your result.
The dot in between the words is there to show that the output really is only the expected output, as extra empty spaces could not be seen with `print` statements.

Comment: This code does not only remove 'fox'. It also removes the preceding '.'. This will fail miserably if the input word (to be removed) doesn't exist. Is a 'word' the same as a substring?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that words in the sentence are each separated by a single space. Then you can make a list of all words using *split()*

Try to remove the specified word. If the word doesn't exist, ValueError will be raised.

If removal succeeds, rejoin the word list

```
sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
print(f"The sentence is: {sentence}")

user_removal = input("Which word would you like to remove? ")

words = sentence.split()

try:
    words.remove(user_removal)
    print(' '.join(words))
except ValueError:
    print(f'Selected word "{user_removal}" is not in the sentence')
```

**Examples:**

```
The sentence is: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
Which word would you like to remove? jumps
The quick brown fox over the lazy dog.

The sentence is: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
Which word would you like to remove? cat
Selected word "cat" is not in the sentence
```